# How to Verify Paypal Account via REST API

Tags: ios, paypal

In my iOS application i am using paypal, so, when user going through signup process i need to verify his paypal account is vaild or not.
i am using the rest API but didn't see any API related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Still there is no way in REST API's to check the validity of a PayPal account by just providing the email address and name .As of now it can only be done using "GetVerifiedStatus" classic API .

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/

Comment: I go through this but that come under section of adaptive-accounts and for this we need API username/ password / signature/ application id and that is different.